# SQL Server 2012 Client Statistics Incorrect

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I run my query, I get the following Client Statistics Results :-

```
Number of SELECT statements = 2
```

The query being ran is only 1 SELECT statement :-

```
SELECT TOP 1000000 * FROM [DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[TABLE]
```

My client statistics returned on the server claiming 2 SELECT statements looks like this :-

### [image]

---

### [image]

Can someone explain why it would show as 2 SELECT statements ?

I have also used SQL Profiler to trace this as its being ran, and there was no second query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retrieving the execution plan is a call as well (this is why you can see an additional `1 row(s) affected` message in the messages pane as well). Try again without the execution plan option.